# mvn -PautoInstallPackage install throwing error Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: maven, aem

getting error Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins  while running command mvn -PautoInstallPackage install for creating AEM 6.3 Project using adobe archetype11, following steps mentioned in article https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/maven_arch11.html. I am using setting.xml available in this article. But when I remove proxy from setting.xml the build was successful using cmd mvn -PautoInstallPackage. **How can I achieve build success without removing proxy tag from setting.xml?** 
used  local.net|some.host.com and  local.net|some.host.com . Still the issue exists. Please provide a help.

Comment: run maven with -X flag and share full error log.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting full .m2/repository local repository may solve your problem.

Or else you need to know what plugins are you using exactly with their dependencies as one of the plugin suffered a problem while downloading